# R not activated in latest 2020.1 pycharm even though plugin is enabled

Tags: pycharm

I just upgraded to `Pycharm` 2020.1 from 2019.3:

[image]

The `R` plugin is enabled - and was working before I did the upgrade from 2019.3 to 2020.1

[image]

But the lovely `R` files have been demoted to *plain text* ..  Note that I had already restarted pycharm..

[image]

Anyone else seeing this?

**Update**  Another tidbit: under `File Types` there is no longer any `R` type (which used to include `.Rmd` for example). Clearly the upgrade lost touch with `R`; and manually installing the latest version of the `R` plugin did not fix the problem.

**Another update**  `R` projects are no longer available from `New Project` types

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you have `respr_test.R` assigned to a text file type. Check **Settings | Editor | File Types | Text | Registered patterns** and remove any `*.R` entries there:

[image]

Comment: Nice try - but no `R` types there

Comment: Which icon is shown next to `respr_test.R` in the project tree? It can be assigned to a different file type. Does highlighting work fine in other R files?

Comment: I had checked multiple `R` files before posting this question: all are plain text.

Comment: btw under `File Types` there is no longer any `R` type (which used to include `.Rmd` for example). Clearly the upgrade to `2020.1` lost touch with `R`

Comment: Got it. Btw do you have "R project" option on the "New project" screen?

Comment: No  `R` there - added screenshot to question

Comment: There's a relevant ticket in R plugin bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/R-656 - the exact issue reason is still unclear but a possible workaround is to remove the plugins folder

Comment: I am awarding since a ticket has been created for this issue with JetBrains. That is a very helpful/productive outcome

Comment: I have the same issue.  Updated both PyCharm (2020.1) and the R plugin (201.5985.142), and now there is no option for R kernel, R doesn't show up in the languages, script that I was just working on is now rendered as plain text.  Plugin still shows up as installed though.  It's installed on MacOS 10.15.4 (Catalina).

Answer (score 1):

1. Enter https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6632-r-language-for-intellij/versions
2. Download version `201.5985.142`
3. Unzip the downloaded archive to get the `rplugin` folder.
4. Copy all the folders `rplugin` to Pycharm ’s plugin directory, for
   example, `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm\plugins`
5. Finally, restart pycharm and you will see that the R plugin is
   enabled

Comment: hi - I had already had added this answer ten days earlier - see below

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is a `release candidate` for `R` on `2020.1`:   https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6632-r-language-for-intellij/update/82596

[image]

I downloaded it and followed the instructions to unzip into `Pycharm.app/plugins`   https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206135879-How-to-install-plugin-manually-

[image]

I am restarting `Pycharm` now - let's see..   (Maybe I should not jump into new versions so eagerly..)

**Update** The downloaded/unzipped version of the `R` plugin is showing up in `plugins`

[image]

However it is **still not working** still `plain text`.  So any answer with a real working approach is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

For macos you can `+x` the `~/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/plugins/rplugin/crashpad_handler-x64-osx` because after the update it lacks execution flag.

edit:
there's a new official resolution: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/R-656#focus=streamItem-27-4078385.0-0

Comment: Yes that was buried in the comments of the accepted answer